# iosでjavascriptを使い「Ctrl+S」のキーイベントを発火させたいです

Tags: javascript, ios

iosでjavascriptを使い「Ctrl+S」のキーイベントを発火させたいですが、できるでしょうか
safari上でテキストを編集し、Svadilfariのジェスチャーで「Ctrl+S」の信号を送りセーブしたいのです
よろしくお願いします

Comment: そもそも iOS の Safari で Ctrl + S のショートカットが (キーボード等を繋いだとしても) 有効なのでしょうか？

Comment: サイトによると思いますが、そのサイトではキーボードを繋いでCtrl+Sを押すとセーブされます
特殊な使い方でもうしわけありません

Comment: document.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent( "keyup",{key: "s" })) ;
これは違うようです